# How to build $\varepsilon$ – $N(\varepsilon)$ proof for this limit?

Tags: limits

Assignment says: Using the definition of the limit of a sequence
(applying the “$\varepsilon$ – $N(\varepsilon)$ language”) prove that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n+4\sqrt{n}-3}{2\sqrt{n}+7} = +\infty$$

Can you please help me?

EDIT: I solved it by separating numerator and denominator, but I don't know how to write it in Epsilon-N Form
[[image: 1]]My solution attempt[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI4St.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI4St.jpg)

EDIT#2:Does that work as a inequality solution?[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please add some more context to your question. For example, you can show your attempts or the source of this assignment.

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Did you mean to write $\lim_{n \to \infty}$?

Comment: Prove what? you have just written down the limit right now

Comment: Do you know the definition of limit when $a_n \to \infty$?

Comment: it's when  there exists a real number L such that for all ε>0, there exists N>0 such that. |f(x)−L|<ε for all x>N, right?

Comment: Oh, now I see why I started getting stuck, something's not correct in my notes, gotta check that

Comment: @ikerra13 It should be something like this: for all $\varepsilon$ there exists $N(\varepsilon)$ such that for all $n>N(\varepsilon)$ we have $a_n>\varepsilon$.

Comment: Let try with this and edit your question showing your work.

Comment: Your definition would be correct if the sequence had the limit $L\in\mathbb{R}$, however when the limit is $\infty$, the definition changes a bit to account for the fact that $\infty$ is not a real number

Comment: OK, thank you very much! Gotta try that again with a correct definition and I'll edit a question as soon as I get some results.

Comment: @ikerra13 Errata corrige to previous comment: $a_n \to L$

Comment: So basically I spent time reading material a bit and solved it algebraically by separating numerator and denominator and proved that limit is infinite, but I don't know how to write it in Epsilon-N form

Comment: @ikerra13 You need to solve this for $ n$ $$\frac{n+4\sqrt{n}-3}{2\sqrt{n}+7}>\varepsilon $$ and you can use some trick.

Comment: @ikerra13 From the given inequality you need to find $N(\varepsilon)$ such that for all $n>N(\varepsilon)$ the inequality holds.

Comment: @ikerra13 No this is not the way to follows. According to the definition of limit, you need to start form here $\frac{n+4\sqrt{n}-3}{2\sqrt{n}+7}>\varepsilon$ and this is ok. Now the problem is: **for what value of $N$ does the inequality hold for any $n>N$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the solutions you've proposed really prove it using the definition, but rather using rules of the limit. That's fine if you want to compute limits in general, and is usually how it's done, however your problem was to specifically show it using the definition. Also, they do not really seem to be correct.

I'll try to give you a somewhat detailed solution to show you how you can deal with limits which seem a bit annoying to work with, like this one.

So we want to show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+4\sqrt{n}-3}{2\sqrt{n}+7}=\infty.$$

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. We now want to find an $N$ (possibly depending on $\varepsilon$) such that

$$\frac{n+4\sqrt{n}-3}{2\sqrt{n}+7}>\varepsilon$$

whenever $n> N$ (this is what the definition says). The way we find such an $N$ is by playing around with the inequality above a bit. So let's start by just finding some smaller expression which is easier to work with and also goes to $\infty$. In particular, notice that

$$\frac{n+4\sqrt{n}-3}{2\sqrt{n}+7}\geq\frac{n-16}{2(\sqrt{n}+4)}=\frac{(\sqrt{n}+4)(\sqrt{n}-4)}{2(\sqrt{n}+4)}=\frac{\sqrt{n}-4}{2}.$$

Now clearly if

$$\frac{\sqrt{n}-4}{2}>\varepsilon,$$

then we also have that

$$\frac{n+4\sqrt{n}-3}{2\sqrt{n}+7}>\varepsilon.$$

Notice how we have just applied a few easy inequalities to reduce the problem to considering something much easier. This is a very useful technique to use when proving limits, as often it lets you simplify difficult problems a lot. Now it is easy to see that

$$\frac{\sqrt{n}-4}{2}>\varepsilon$$

if and only if

$$n>(2\varepsilon+4)^2.$$

Thus setting

$$N=(2\varepsilon+4)^2$$

we are done.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you very much!!
That's really useful!

Comment: I have a question tho, did we choose (n-16)/(2(sqrt(n)+4) just because we knew it is smaller then the initial inequality?

Comment: We choose $\frac{n-16}{2(\sqrt{n}+4)}$ specifically because it let us do the cancellation in the next step. So we could've just as well done something different which was smaller than the original expression, but this allowed us to completely get rid of the $n$-dependence in the denominator in a really easy way

Comment: Ooooh, okay, thank you again, this really helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, by the definition of limit we need

$$\frac{n+4\sqrt{n}-3}{2\sqrt{n}+7}>\varepsilon $$

then, in order to simplify, we can proceed as follows using that

- $n+4\sqrt{n}-3>n \iff 4\sqrt{n}>3$
- $9\sqrt{n}\ge2\sqrt{n}+7 \iff \sqrt{n}\ge1$

we have

$$\frac{n+4\sqrt{n}-3}{2\sqrt{n}+7}>\frac{n}{9\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sqrt n}9{} $$

and then it suffices that

$$\frac{\sqrt n}9{}>\varepsilon \iff n>N(\varepsilon)=\lceil 81\varepsilon^2\rceil$$